# Error when I select a given data p:datatable rg.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getRowData(

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I'm using prime faces data table in my application where i have
when I select any of a given table

it returns me the following error

someone help?
I used primefaces 3.5

jsf 2.1

My dataTable of primefaces

```
lazyDataModel = new LazyDataModel<Funcionario>() 
        {

            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



            @Override
            public List<Funcionario> load(int first, int pageSize,
                    String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder,
                    Map<String, String> filters) {

                try {
                    funcionarios = funcionarioService.listar(first, pageSize, filters);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }


                if(getRowCount() <= 0)
                {
                    setRowCount(funcionarioService.getRowCount());
                }

                setPageSize(pageSize);

                super.setWrappedData(funcionarios);

                return funcionarios;
            }


            @Override
            public Object getRowKey(Funcionario item) {
                System.out.println(item.getCodigo());
                return item.getCodigo();
            }



            @Override
            public Funcionario getRowData(String rowKey) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Integer id = Integer.valueOf(rowKey);

                for (Funcionario funcionario : (List<Funcionario>) getWrappedData()) {

                    if(id.equals(funcionario.getCodigo()))
                    {
                        return funcionario;
                    }

                }

                return null;
            }


            @Override
            public void setRowIndex(int rowIndex) {
                /*
                 * The following is in ancestor (LazyDataModel):
                 * this.rowIndex = rowIndex == -1 ? rowIndex : (rowIndex % pageSize);
                 */
                if (rowIndex == -1 || getPageSize() == 0) {
                    super.setRowIndex(-1);
                }
                else
                    super.setRowIndex(rowIndex % getPageSize());
            }

        };
    }
```

my listagem.xhtml

```
    ?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">  

      <h:head>

      </h:head> 

      <h:form id = "f">      

          <p:dataTable emptyMessage="Não tem registros." var = "funcionario" 
          value = "#{bean.getLazyDataModel()}" paginator="true" rows = "5" id = "tbf" 
          rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" lazy = "true" filterEvent="enter" 
          selection="#{bean.selecionado}" selectionMode="single" rowKey="#{bean.funcionario.codigo}"
          >


              <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":t:dialogf:display" oncomplete="funcionarioDialog.show()"/>

              <p:column filterBy="#{funcionario.codigo}" headerText="Codigo" filterMatchMode="contains" 
              >
                  <h:outputText value="#{funcionario.codigo}" />    
              </p:column>    

              <p:column filterBy="#{funcionario.nome}" headerText="Nome" filterMatchMode="contains">  
                  <h:outputText value="#{funcionario.nome}" />
              </p:column>

              <p:column filterBy="#{funcionario.cpf}" headerText="Cpf" filterMatchMode="contains">
                  <h:outputText value="#{funcionario.cpf}" />    
              </p:column>

              <p:column filterBy="#{funcionario.dataNascimento}" headerText="Data Nascimento" filterMatchMode="contains" >
                  <h:outputText value="#{funcionario.dataNascimento}" >
                      <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                  </h:outputText>    
              </p:column>

              <p:column filterBy="#{funcionario.usuario}" headerText="Usuario" filterMatchMode="contains">
                  <h:outputText value="#{funcionario.usuario}" />    
              </p:column>

              <p:column headerText = "Excluir">

                  <p:commandLink action ="#{funcionarioBean.excluir()}" update = "tbf" >
                  excluir
                  <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{funcionarioBean.funcionario}" value="#{funcionario}" />
                  </p:commandLink>

              </p:column>


              <p:column style="width:4%">  
                <p:commandButton id="selectButton" update = ":t:dialogf:display" value = "ver"
                oncomplete="funcionarioDialog.show()" title="View"> 
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.selecionado}" value="#{funcionario}" />  
                </p:commandButton>  
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText = "Alterar">  
                <p:commandButton id="selectButton2" update = ":t:" value = "Alterar" title="Alterar"> 
                    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.funcionario}" value="#{funcionario}" />  
                </p:commandButton>  
            </p:column> 

          </p:dataTable>          
      </h:form>

      <h:form id = "dialogf">
          <p:dialog id = "dialog" header = "Detalhes do Registro" widgetVar="funcionarioDialog" resizable = "false"
          showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">

              <h:panelGrid id = "display" columns="2" cellpadding="4">

                  <h:outputText value="Codigo:" />  
                   <h:outputText value="#{bean.selecionado.codigo}" />

                  <h:outputText value="Nome:" />  
                   <h:outputText value="#{bean.funcionario.nome}" />

                   <h:outputText value="Cpf:" />  
                   <h:outputText value="#{bean.funcionario.cpf}" /> 

                   <h:outputText value="Data Nascimento:" />  
                   <h:outputText value="#{bean.funcionario.dataNascimento}" >
                       <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                   </h:outputText> 

                   <h:outputText value="Usuario:" />  
                   <h:outputText value="#{bean.funcionario.usuario}" /> 

                   <h:outputText value="Senha:" />  
                   <h:outputText value="#{bean.funcionario.senha}" /> 


              </h:panelGrid>

          </p:dialog>
      </h:form>


</html>
```

error

```
    Set 04, 2013 9:40:56 AM com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl processPartial
INFO: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getRowData(DataTable.java:936)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decodeSingleSelection(SelectionFeature.java:47)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.feature.SelectionFeature.decode(SelectionFeature.java:38)
    at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.decode(DataTableRenderer.java:57)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.decode(UIComponentBase.java:787)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.processDecodes(UIData.java:228)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:506)
    at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
    at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.visitTree(UIData.java:639)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1600)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:344)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1600)
    at org.primefaces.component.tabview.TabView.visitTree(TabView.java:419)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1600)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1600)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:376)
    at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:252)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:183)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:931)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: It looks like your `getRowData(String)` function is not being called; instead, it is calling the `super` version of the function. Is it possible that your `bean.getLazyDataModel()` method is returning a different type of `ListDataModel`?

Comment: My beans returns this class org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel<Funcionario>